# Firebase unique ID without registration

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create an App where the user doesn't have to register sign in but where the sing in is done automatically when the user opens the app. However the user should be able to deleted and download the app again without creating a new user ID when opening the app. Is that possible?

Thats something that the Jodel App is doing, where users do not have to register. Is there any unique identifier that can be used to store users?

Comment: Have you checked out [Anonymous Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did in one of my apps is to use the email registration (programmatically) with a random email and a random password created by the app itself. You can store those credentials in the preferences to use it the next time to sign in.

It is a workaround I think, but with that the user don't see any registration and you have an id in firebase connected to a device/user.

You need to handle the problem if the user deletes the app, but you could show him in a different screen his credentials the app is using for further use.